# Is it possible to write text to an image using Pillow and then extracting said text?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Basically, I want to write text to an image using Pillow Python3. Is there something I can do or some pre-processing before/after writing text to an image that would enable me to read in back the text without using things like Tesseract?

Comment: What format is your file - JPEG or PNG or other?

Comment: I'm currently using PNG, but I hope to expand to other image extensions. I'm trying to do steganography. So I'm writing a character to each pixel of an image, but I'm having trouble getting those characters back.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pytesser` for this:

```
from pytesser import * 
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open(filename)
print(image_to_string(image))
```